# C# data to datagridview does not reloaded

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, datagridview

Am trying to reload data to `datagridview` when i click on `refresh` button but data is not refreshed after click. Am using `MySQL` database and when i start program i go in database manager `SQLYog` and manually make changes in that row. After that i switch to my app and press refresh button to se does app work but nothing is happening. I dont know what i do wrong and whay data in grid is not refreshed...

**Here is my code:**

```
class MainWindow : Form
{
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    private MySqlCommandBuilder cmd;
    private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    // Get data
    public void GetData(string sql)
    {        
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                bs.DataSource = dt;                           
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }           
    }

    // Load
    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        GetData("SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala");
    }

   // Reload click
    private void reload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData(adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's MySql problem, I checked your code with MsSql and works fine. You said that you add record with `SQLYog`, Does `SqlYog` and `MySqlConnection` conflicts?

Comment: no evrerything work perfect. But i dont know what is this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    class MainWindow : Form
    {
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    private MySqlCommandBuilder cmd;
    private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala";

    // Constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    // Get data
    public void GetData(string sql)
    {        
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                bs.DataSource = dt;                           
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }           
    }

    // Load
    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        GetData(sql);
    }

   // Reload click
    private void reload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        GetData(sql);
        datagridview1.update();
        datagridview1.refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: No does not work. Again result is the some. When i edit in database and press reload button nothhing is happening!

Comment: @Ivan or maybe you need to use this sentences after the call to **GetData** Method: `datagridview1.update();`
`datagridview1.refresh();`

Comment: @Ivan i edited the code with the update and refresh methods for the datagridview

Comment: Nope again not working. I relay dont understand what is happening

Comment: @Ivan Ok, I edited the code once more, please try again

Comment: thanks for helping but again not working. Maybe is `MySQL` problem

Comment: @Ivan you need to search more about this problem, but no problem,I tried to help you!

Comment: I will try this but  on SQL server to check. Myb is Mysql problem

Answer (score -3):

You should write this. This might solve your problem

```
class MainWindow : Form
{
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    private MySqlCommandBuilder cmd;
    private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Constructor
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    // Get data
    public void GetData(string sql)
    {        
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                bs.DataSource = dt;                           
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }           
    }

    // Load
    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM grupe_artikala";
    }

   // Reload click
    private void reload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData(sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will definetly gives error. `String sql` is not reachable on `reload_Click event`. And what is the output when the form loaded?

Comment: That what u say is realy bad. Sorry bu i cant accept that answer